# Oracle Apex fixed page or region size

Tags: oracle-apex, apex, fixed-width

I am creating a desk booking application in oracle Apex and I have a page with the images of desks to be booked. the whole page should look like this (I used buttons in columns in the region) :
[image]

but when the screen size changes, from device to another device, the space between columns get bigger like this:

[image]

how can I set the page or the region to have the fixed size and dont change based on different devices?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

One option is to navigate to region's properties and put something like this into the "Custom attributes" property:

```
style="width:400px;height:200px"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works on the windows devices but when I try to open it from the phon size device, it doesn't work!

Comment: explain "it doesn't work" what is the behaviour you're seeing ?

Comment: the buttons do not come in a row (each row must have 4 buttons), but all off them com in separate rows (each row has just one button)